# KeyDown event doesn't raise

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with a button in. I want to capture the Form.KeyDown event.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.gameRunning)
   {
       this.buttonStrat.Text = "Pause";
       this.timer1.Enabled = true;
   }
   else
   {
       this.buttonStart.Text = "Continue";
       this.timer1.Enabled = false;
   }
   this.gameRunning = !this.gameRunning;
}
```

However, I was disabling `buttonStart` without supporting PAUSE and it was working nice. Since I have added the PAUSE advantage, the `Form.KeyDown` event doesn't raise and `buttonStart` is `Focuse`d. Whenever I disable `buttonStart`, it fires.

NOTES:

- I have set `Form.KeyPreview` to `true`, stills doesn't raise
- I have set `Form.AcceptButton` to `null`, stills doesn't raise
- I have made `buttonStart` subscriped to `Form.KeyDown`, stills doesn't.

Comment: Override the form's OnProcessCmdKey() to reliably catch shortcut keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will helps you ..

---

Override **IsInputKey** behaviour

---

You must override the **IsInputKey** behavior to inform that you want the Right Arrow key to be treated as an InputKey and not as a special behavior key.
For that you must override the method for each of your controls.
I would advise you to create your won Buttons, let's say **MyButton**

The class below creates a custom Button that overrides the **IsInputKey** method so that the right arrow key is not treated as a special key. From there you can easily make it for the other arrow keys or anything else.

```
    public partial class MyButton : Button
    {
        protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Right)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Afterwards, you can treat your keyDown event event in each different Button or in the form itself:

In the Buttons' KeyDown Method try to set these properties:

```
private void myButton1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
  //DoSomething();
}
```

-- OR --

handle the common behaviour in the form: (do not set *e.Handled = true;* in the buttons)

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //DoSomething();
}
```